# JQuery MObile calling Java Method

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

im trying to do a button that show a alert in the android phone, but nothing happens, the buttons is propertly rendered(i have jquery, jquery mobile, js in assets folder)

```
    ...

        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
            WebView webview = new WebView(this);
            WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            setContentView(webview);
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            webview.addJavascriptInterface(this,"alerts");


            setContentView(webview);
    }

public void showAlert() {
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main);
        builder.setTitle("Test WORKED?");
    builder.setMessage("Yes if you see -_-");
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

}
```

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///android_asset/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="file:///android_asset/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="file:///android_asset/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<button type="submit" onclick="javascript:showalert();">ShowAlert</button>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function showalert() {
   alerts.showAlert();
  )};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and other question is: how do i map this kind of jquery button to do something:

```
<button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

your code has script error.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function showalert() {
   alerts.showAlert();
  )};   //<-----  replace please ..  });
</script>
```

and then

add annotation ?

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void showAlert() {
    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(main);
    builder.setTitle("Test WORKED?");
    builder.setMessage("Yes if you see -_-");
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: thanks, its trying to do the method now, but return me this in logcat:
`
04-03 23:02:36.201: I/chromium(15316): [INFO:CONSOLE(17)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'showAlert'", source: file:///android_asset/index.html (17)`


but i have the method =(

Comment: WORKED, JESUS CHRIST I LOVE YOU ;)!!

yes looking now, i think was the missing decoration like (@ManagedBean, etc...)

Some stup1d guy voted you down, and i dont have points to up ;'(

Comment: oh!! 
I don't care!!
good luck!!

and .. 
decoration is wrong ??? 
annotation is right ???

Comment: the annotation is right, but this part is not working -> 
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this),"alerts"); the original works